# How to get the current VIM mode as a string

Tags: vim

I've build my own statusline in VIM with, to show the current mode indicator I use:

```
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(mode()=='n')?'\ \ NORMAL\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#InsertColor#%{(mode()==?'i')?'\ \ INSERT\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#ReplaceColor#%{(mode()==?'R')?'\ \ RPLACE\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(mode()==#'v')?'\ \ VISUAL\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(mode()==#'V')?'\ \ V-LINE\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(mode()=='\<C-V>')?'\ \ V-BLOCK\ ':''}
```

It works for all the modes except for the V-BLOCK. Is there a way to match the '\< C-V>' with such approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should help you. The `^V` has ascii value 22:

```
.....%{(mode()==nr2char(22))?'\ \ V-BLOCK\ ':''}
```